# Swift: add button target in an inner class

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I'm trying to set an action to call on a button touch. I created the *button* in *IB*, and in the main class I'm trying to set the needed action.

After all set up, I touch the button and nothing happens. I guess there is a problem with *target* or *action selector*: which in this case I should use? Thanks!

```
class View: UIView {

    private class PhoneCallSetter: UIResponder {

      private var phone: String!

      func initialize(button: UIButton!, phoneNumber: String!) {
        self.phone = phoneNumber

        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(PhoneCallSetter.call), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
      }

      @objc func call() {
        if let phoneCallURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: "tel://\(phone)") {
            let application: UIApplication = UIApplication.sharedApplication()
            if (application.canOpenURL(phoneCallURL)) {
                application.openURL(phoneCallURL);
            }
        }
      }
   }

@IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!

// somewhere down there I call
func setPhone() {
    PhoneCallSetter().initialize(button, phoneNumber: "123-456")
}}
```

Comment: You can simply create the button action in UIView class. In that method you can call a block that would define in your main controller class.

Comment: have you hooked an `@IBAction` from your button to the method `setPhone()`?

Comment: @Amanpreet it sound like an option, but I need to pass a value in that function (call) then, shall I somehow associate it with my button?

Comment: @sargeras why do I need to do that? I made sure that setPhone get called.

Comment: @Леопольд Блум I have edited my answer. Now you can pass data in block.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. You show the definintion of a custom UIView subclass, but then you show an IBOutlet and a function setPhone floating, not part of any class. Where are that outlet and function declared?

Comment: @DuncanC sorry for misleading. button and setPhone() are in View class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `setPhone()` method, you create a new instance of `PhoneCallSetter`, and calling its method `initialize(_:phoneNumber:)`, but you are not keeping the instance anywhere.

For an object to be an action target, the object needs to be kept somewhere with a strong reference. `UIButton` (or any other `UIControl`) just holds the target object with weak reference.

Which means, once the method `initialize(_:phoneNumber:)` has finished execution, the instance of `PhoneCallSetter` is released. An action method sent to already released instance may be ignored silently.

Thus, you need to keep the instance with strong reference, such as:

```
var phoneCallSetter: PhoneCallSetter?
func setPhone() {
    self.phoneCallSetter = PhoneCallSetter()
    self.phoneCallSetter!.initialize(button, phoneNumber: "123-456")
}
```

---

But I do not understand why you dare make a private class as an action target. Non-standard way forces you to make non-standard effort, which you'd better avoid.

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly the reason. Also, I'm taking your advice and now rewriting the code, it really looked not in place...

Answer (score 0):

For Example:

```
class FV_OrderComplete: UIView {
   var block_OrderSubmit: (() -> ())!
    var block_checkPincode: ((String) -> ())!

    @IBAction func didActButtonOK(_ sender: AnyObject)
        {
            if block_OrderSubmit != nil{
                block_OrderSubmit()
            }

           if block_checkPincode != nil{
            block_checkPincode(txtField_Pincode.text!)
        }
    }
}
```

In Controller class use the block where you want. It will only call when you press the button:

```
self.vew.block_OrderSubmit  =
            {
                ()in
               //write code
        }

      self.vew.block_checkPincode =
        {
            (str_Pincode: String) in
             //write code and use the passed data
        }
```

Note: Here **vew** is object of UIView class.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like the problem is your `setPhone()` function. That function creates a new instance of your `PhoneCallSetter` class and then calls it's initialize method, but you then never do anything with that object. You should either create a UIView object in your storyboard and change it's class to `PhoneCallSetter` (probably best) or add a PhoneCallSetter object to your view hierarchy in code. (But that would mean setting up constraints on it, which is a little tricky.)

Answer (score 0):

your target in inner class should be nested(inherited)

button.addTarget(View. PhoneCallSetter, action: #selector(PhoneCallSetter.call), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the name of button outlet here:

```
@IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!
```

your function

```
func initialize(button: UIButton!, phoneNumber: String!)
```

is not able to recognise the actual button pressed, as you have the button name same at both the places.